# Could not set excel chart style

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts

Below is my code,

```
Public Sub createdonutchart(Chartrange1 As String, chartrange2 As String, L1 As Integer, T1 As Integer, W1 As Integer, H1 As Integer, targetsheet As Worksheet, charttitle As String)

        Dim oChart As Excel.Chart
        Dim MyCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
        Dim MyCharts1 As Excel.ChartObject
        MyCharts = targetsheet.ChartObjects
        MyCharts1 = MyCharts.Add(L1, T1, W1, H1)
        oChart = MyCharts1.Chart

        With oChart
            Dim chartRange As Excel.Range
            chartRange = targetsheet.Range(Chartrange1, chartrange2)
            .SetSourceData(chartRange)
            .PlotBy = Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns
            .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlDoughnut
            .ChartStyle = 3
            .ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowNone)
            .HasLegend = True
            .Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionRight
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = charttitle
        End With

    End Sub
```

I have used chart.chartstyle=3 to change chart style to 3, but excel still shows chart with basic chart style, see attached image.

Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

'3' is not a valid chart type...

See MSDN Page for XlChartType Enumeration and select one of those.

Link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838409.aspx

Comment: It's not charttype it's chartstle... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.chartstyle.aspx